# Magento Design issue for category detail page

Tags: magento

I suffered with a issue in magento 1.8.1.0 that i saved design 'default' for website and also set setting as website for its Store. but when i saw in category detail page , where all product of that category shown has different design from configured design ? so please tell me what the things has to done to rectify this problem. thanks in advance

Comment: Please show demo atleast.

Comment: Cache cleared? Just a wild spontanous guess.

Comment: first of all Please gothrough with below,That's how magento theme fall back works,
your pkg> your theme
your pkg > default theme ( you can set default theme at backend)
your pckg > default
base > default

Also, Please clear magento cache before you check anything.

Answer (score 1):

first of all Please gothrough with below,That's how magento theme fall back works,

```
your pkg> your theme
your pkg > default theme ( you can set default theme at backend)
your pckg > default
base > default
```

Also, Please clear magento cache before you check anything.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error , because of i added a design in system -> design and i add an entry for my website is instead of 'default' to another theme , thats why i got category and other page was come with a deferent category. because these setting has the highest priority in design selection for magento. thanks for you comments.